# rename a file based on part of the original name

Tags: bash, awk

Everday we get a new backup dump of a database eg:

```
thisfile.0.db2v22.DODE0000.CATN00000.20180627132924.001
thisfile.0.db2v22.DODE0000.CATN00000.20180628132924.001
thisfile.0.db2v22.DODE0000.CATN00000.20180629132924.001
```

and from that dump is the date which is in the 6th position of the file name eg: `20180627132924`.

I need to write a script that will strip the date and time eg: `20180627132924` from that file in the folder and insert into a restore script.

How do I grab this date so I can add it as a variable within my restore script?

maybe something like :

```
OUTPUT="$(ls -l *.001 | awk -F '[_.]' '{print $6}')"
echo " restore $(OUTPUT) to this" >>restore 
chmod 700 restore
./restore
```

Comment: Sounds like you might have a question - see [ask] for how to get help in this forum..

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please [edit] your question. Also, have a look at [ask].

Comment: It seems that your `restore` script needs to take an argument so you can execute it as `./restore 20180627132924`, but better would be that you just pass the filename.

Answer (score 2):

In case of the filename you propose, I would suggest to use pure Bash built-in functions :

```
$ file="thisfile.0.db2v22.DODE0000.CATN00000.20180627132924.001"
$ fname=${file%.*}
$ fname=${fname##*.}
$ echo $fname
20180627132924
$ echo "This is the file name ${fname} and it has been backup." > outputfile
```

Comment: I -thought- that was what it was doing.  Still, I always have to Google those tricky bash builtins.  Your question deciphering skills are top-notch.  :)